# Non repeating series of non repeating numbers

Tags: c++, random

I will try to describe my problem as good as i can, since it's my first time here :)

So, i have to write a program in C++ wich as you may or may not guessed from the title, prints to screen a serie of random numbers that do not repeat either in the numbers themself and the serie.

I have 4 "slots" to fill with the serie of numbers. And the numbers can randomize from 0 to 4 (wich cannot repeat).

What i mean to do is this:

SLOT 1: 1 3 2 4

SLOT 2: 3 1 4 2       <----- As you can see, they do not repeat horizontally, nor vertically

SLOT 3: 2 4 3 1

SLOT 4: 4 2 1 3

This is the code i've came up with, until i got stuck (it is a preety ugly code, i know)

```
    void MC_Slot_Rand()
{
    text.setDefaultColor("white");//don't mind this
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
    int n4;
    int number;
    int slotN = 0;
    int slotN_2 = 1;
        while (slotN < dim)
        {
            color.red();//don't mind this
            cout << "SLOT " << slotN_2 << ":  ";
            color.white();//don't mind this either
            n1 = 1;//RESET 
                   //for some reason, if i don't put 1
                   // the program repeats the numbers
            n2, n3, n4 = 10;//RESET
            do
            {
                number = rand() % 4;
            } while (number == n1);
            n1 = number;

            do
            {
                number = rand() % 4;
            } while (number == n1);
            n2 = number;

            do
            {
                number = rand() % 4;
            } while (number == n1 || number == n2);
            n3 = number;

            do
            {
                number = rand() % 4;
            } while (number == n1 || number == n2 || number == n3);
            n4 = number;

            //cout << n1 << n2 << n3 << n4;//debug
            MC_ENUM(n1);
            MC_ENUM(n2);//this function simply takes the number and
                        //transforms it into a letter using a switch statement
                        // example: 0 = A, 1 = B, etcetera...

            MC_ENUM(n3);
            MC_ENUM(n4);
            ut.spacer(3);//this function does cout<<endl; as many times
                         //as the number specifies
            slotN++;
            slotN_2++;

        }

}//END OF FUNCTION
```

What this piece of code does, is simply printing 4 series of non repeating numbers, BUT the numbers repeat vertically! And of course i don't want that to happen.

I hope someone more experienced than me out there can help me :)

Very important: If you want to try this code, cancel the lines commented with `don't mind this`, `MC_ENUM();` functions and also `ut.spacer();` as they are part of a library of mine and won't work with you :P

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you remove the qt tag as it has nothing to do with it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to this community. I added the qt because it was suggested by the site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:
When you need the numbers to be unique, rather than generating random numbers, what you do is generate an array of all the unique numbers you want. In this case it's an array of length 4 with the values [1,2,3,4].
Now, shuffle the array randomly using a known good shuffling algorithm that guarantees near-equal opportunity to all permutations. If you want to prevent a certain digit from appearing in the same index, you can easily add a rule in the shuffle that requires unique placement for each shuffled digit.

Here's yet another approach: this approach is particularly good for small lengths. Generate all possible permutations and then pick a permutation at random. To uphold your additional requirement you simply disregard the non-fitting permutations. A clear advantage to this method is that it is entirely deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, what you're doing is producing a randomised vector of all permutations of the numbers 1-4.

Fortunately the answer is in the standard library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool column_match(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2)
{
    auto N = std::min(v1.size(), v2.size());
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i) {
        if (v1[i] == v2[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    vector<vector<int>> series;
    do {
        series.push_back(nums);
    } while (next_permutation(begin(nums), end(nums)));

    random_shuffle(begin(series), end(series));

    vector<vector<int>> result;
    copy_if(begin(series), end(series), back_inserter(result), [&](const auto& candidate){
        return !any_of(begin(result), end(result), [&](const auto& check){
            return column_match(candidate, check);
        });
    });

    for (const auto& s : result) {
        copy(begin(s), end(s), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ","));
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
4,3,1,2,
3,2,4,1,
1,4,2,3,
2,1,3,4,
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: added a final filter stage to only return the first available candidate square. It should be trivial to repeat this to produce all squares simply by removing accepted candidates from the series and repeating the filter until the series is empty.

Comment: Great answer. I like it because it makes full use of the standard library. A little correction: it should be :`auto N = std::min(...`. If vectors are of same length like now it doesn't make a difference, but for the general case you need min, not max.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud do it like this and this is my thought

fistly,you should define arry like a[4][4],when it produces a number you store the num in arry,then the next numbet is produced,compare it to others in this line horizontally,if it repeats and produce next,if not and store it

when the first line is done,in the second line when produce a number you not only compare it to this line horizontally but also to other lines vertically

like this one line by on line,you will make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat.  You already have one solution in your question:

```
1 3 2 4
3 1 4 2
2 4 3 1
4 2 1 3
```

You can use that solution to generate others.  First, convert that solution to letters:

```
A C B D
C A D B
B D C A
D B A C
```

Second, pick a random mapping from the four letters, A, B, C, D to the four digits, 1, 2, 3, 4.  Replace the letters in your grid with the corresponding digit from your mapping.  That will give a solution.

For further possible solutions, you can exchange columns in your grid or exchange rows in your grid, though some of the resulting grids may be disallowed.  You will need to check things more carefully if you do that.